# How do I turn up the water pressure to my kitchen sink?

Tags: water-pressure

A while ago I had a "professional" contracted through a major company install a hot water heater in the basement: well the hot water heater works fine but the "professional" managed to turn the water pressure to my kitchen sink to a low trickle coming out of the hot water and a slightly more stronger flow from the cold. I cannot run my portable dishwasher let alone do too many dishes at once. I use to have great water pressure before this guy came along. I have checked both dials under the sink and they are all the way turned up..... I do not know exactly what this man did; all I know is he had an attitude problem, wrecked my front screen door, and left a mess in the basement.

My house was built in 1958 but before I moved in they did some major renovations including all new plumbing (minus the hot water heater).

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to turn the water pressure up to my kitchen sink so I can run my portable dishwasher?

Please let me know what other information I can provide that would help solve the problem if need be.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the valves going to and from the new water heater are fully open? You might also check for kinks in the inlet and outlets.

Comment: Might also be worth unscrewing the [faucet aerator](https://www.google.com/#q=faucet+aerator), removing the screen/filter, washing it off...in case it's a little clogged. Sometimes doing work on one side of a system can result in gunk moving downstream to a device at another side of the system.

Comment: Someone in my neighborhood asked me to examine a bathroom faucet which was not providing good flow. The aerator was almost entirely plugged. An easy fix is to unscrew the aerator and soak it in vinegar. Maybe I took it apart; can't remember.

Answer (score 2):

If the water pressure and flow are OK in the rest of the house the problem of low flow in the kitchen is with the shut off valves under the sink or the faucet. one or all are restricted with something. That something could be dirt or calcium from the old tank or the water lines. If the faucet is newer, most have small fittings and small lines that can plug or be restricted easily. I have had to replace the valves under my sink and clean out the fittings for the connecting lines in the faucet.